# Error message for installing package "ggRandomForests" in R

Tags: r, installation-package

I am a beginner in R, so maybe the solution is obvious (if so, I am sorry). I tried to install the package "ggRandomForests" in R (Version: 4.1.2) and I got this message:

Warning in install.packages :
package ‘ggRandomForests’ is not available for this version of R

I googled the problem and found some solutions that I tried but they didn't work:

1. I tried installing "ggRandomForest" since someone suggested that but that gives the same error message.
2. I also tried taking an older version of ggRandomForests from this website: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/randomForest/, stored the URL in a variable and tried to install it like that, but that also didn't work (no error message, just nothing happens). This was my code for that:

urlPackage <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/randomForest/randomForest_4.6-14.tar.gz"
install.packages(urlPackage, repos=NULL, type="source")

Maybe I am missing something or does someone know what the problem is?

Specifically I want to use gg_vimp(), so maybe someone knows an alternative?

Comment: From CRAN regarding this package: "Archived on 2022-02-23 as requires archived package 'randomForestSRC'."

Comment: Thank you!. I do have "randomForestSRC" installed, so I think that should work.